# Xamarin: Error retrieveing parent for item CardView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

### Setup

I'm very new to Xamarin, and I'm trying to follow the official docs as well as implement a [Lollipop Material Design Style](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/ThemeSwitcher) in a dummy app.

I have added the resources that appear in that repo:

[image]

*(turns out, `values-v21` is the right folder name, unlike it is on the repo)*

And then I've also installed from the SDK manager the whole Android API 21 folder and also installed the NuGet `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` which appears correctly in my packages.config AFAIK:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.0.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.0.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid50" />
</packages>
```

### Error

But when I hit play (Debug mode with the API 21 as target) I get these three errors:

```
Build FAILED.
Errors:

/Users/pegasus/Projects/DistraeMe/DistraeMe/DistraeMe.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (_UpdateAndroidResgen target) ->

    Resources/values-v21/styles.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'CardView'.
    Resources/values-v21/styles.xml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'cardBackgroundColor'.
    Resources/values-v21/styles.xml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'cardCornerRadius'.
```

This is the styles.xml pasted from the repo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <!-- Define a custom theme that derives from the light Material Theme -->
  <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">

    <!-- Override the app bar color -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/my_blue</item>

    <!-- Override the color of UI controls -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/my_purple</item>

  </style>

  <!-- Theme an individual view: -->
  <style name="CardView.MyBlue">

    <!-- Change the background color to Xamarin blue: -->
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/my_blue</item>

    <!-- Make the corners very round: -->
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">18dp</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

Am I not linking correctly those resources? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check that might be causing the problem:

1) Use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` instead of `Theme.Material.Light` if you're using AppCompat controls/activities

2) Is your activity inheriting from `AppCompatActivity`?

3) Set the parent of the CardView style to `parent="CardView"`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, I got the same error messages;

```
error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'CardView'.
error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'cardBackgroundColor'.
error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'cardCornerRadius'.
```

The solution:
I just had to **add the nuget package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView**